# Как декодировать строчку в читабельный вид?

Tags: python, utf-8

```
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

soup_utf = soup.encode()

print(soup_utf)
```

Выдает следующий результат:
\xc3\x8e\xc3\xb8\xc3\xa8\xc3\xa1\xc3\xaa\xc3\xa0: \xc3\x8f\xc3\xae\xc3\xab\xc3\xbc\xc3\xa7\xc3\xae\xc3\xa2\xc3\xa0\xc3\xb2\xc3\xa5\xc3\xab\xc3\xbc \xc3\xad\xc3\xa5 \xc3\xae\xc3\xaf\xc3\xb0\xc3\xa5\xc3\xa4\xc3\xa5\xc3\xab\xc3\xa5\xc3\xad

Как преобразовать print(soup_utf) в читабельный формат?

Comment: Вы превращаете читабельные текст в последовательность байт вызовом `encode()`. Используйте  `print(soup)`

Comment: Получилось ли решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Очень похоже на то, что символы - это `UTF-8 (in literal)`, попробуйте преобразовать данную строку в байты и декодировать её.

```
>>> b = b'\xc3\x8e\xc3\xb8\xc3\xa8\xc3\xa1\xc3\xaa\xc3\xa0: \xc3\x8f\xc3\xae\xc3\xab\xc3\xbc\xc3\xa7\xc3\xae\xc3\xa2\xc3\xa0\xc3\xb2\xc3\xa5\xc3\xab\xc3\xbc \xc3\xad\xc3\xa5 \xc3\xae\xc3\xaf\xc3\xb0\xc3\xa5\xc3\xa4\xc3\xa5\xc3\xab\xc3\xa5\xc3\xad'
>>> print(b.decode('utf-8'))
Îøèáêà: Ïîëüçîâàòåëü íå îïðåäåëåí
```

Comment: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex